# What's the biggest source of light?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In *Minecraft*, there are blocks that work as a light sources, and some blocks emit more light than others.

What's the biggest source of light in minecraft?

Comment: The obvious answer is 'The Sun' however I don't think this is what you're looking for ;)

Comment: Correct, the sun is not a block :)

Comment: @djsmiley2k Exactly, that wasn't what I was searching! But thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the [minecraft wiki page on light](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Light):

> There are 16 light levels, which are specified by an integer from 0 (the minimum) to 15 (the maximum). The game uses the light level of a block to compute the brightness of a given block.

Then from the [light emitting blocks part of the page:](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Light#Blocks)

With level 15

1. Beacon
2. End portal block
3. Fire
4. Glowstone
5. Jack o lantern
6. Lava
7. Red stone lamp
8. Sea lantern

The other sources of light are below 15 so the blocks above are the best sources of light.

For comparison a torch is level 14, and a red-stone torch 7.